# Functional Data structures to support flow control

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I'd like to find a functional data structure that can perform "Flow control".

Example: For any IP visiting my website, if the IP has visited >= N times since M minutes ago, the IP is restricted to visit for Z minutes.

Is there any solution that does not require timer (to remove visit records periodically) or large data storage (to remember all the visits from all IPs)?

Can use JAVA or Scala to construct the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answers are **Yes**, **No** and **Yes**.

**Yes**, you can do it without a timer, you only need a single clock. When a request arrives you look at the clock and decide based on the historic data whether to reject the request or not according to your algorithm.

**No**, you can't do this without recording up to N visit records for each IP. You need to know the time of each request to know how many occurred in the last M minutes. There are various ways of compressing this but you can't implement your algorithm without recording every visit.

**Yes**, you can use Java or Scala to create the appropriate data structures based on your algorithm.

**However** you can reduce the data storage if you modify your test. For example you could divide time into windows of length M and count the requests in each window. If the number of requests in the current and previous windows exceeds N then you reject the request. This doesn't give exactly the same results but it achieves the general goal of rate-limiting requests from over-active clients while storing only two values for each IP address.